# Techniques for using native php as a smoothly inline-able templating engine

Tags: php, templates, coding-style

### Goal: Best system for refactoring complex & ugly code in exactly the same file.

I'm currently in the process of refactoring someone else's bad code.  The code is intermixed, procedural php and I want to be able to create templates -in- the script.  I don't want to have to create an external file of a different type to run the template, I want to be able to take the horrible stuff happening in a script and make it into a template in the script, and then call that template right where the horrible stuff once was.  And still be able to see what the template is outputting in the same file.

I just recently rediscovered php's alternative syntax to simplify native templating ( http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php ).

### Example System

Are there other techniques for really simplifying the templating process with native php templates?  I generally prefer another template engine because it makes the php echoing slightly simpler than using php syntax, but especially when refactoring other people's code, sometimes a templating engine is a lot of overhead and imposes a lot of rules, such as having your templates in some "templates" folder seperate from the script you're refactoring, which makes it difficult for placement when refactoring.

Specifically, I'm trying to embark on a project to create a "templating" system that relies on native php, with templates that can be inline in source php scripts.  The reason that I'm doing this is because I've found that, at least in the initial stage, having to switch from template to calling script, back and forth, makes it slightly harder to deal with, and since I am refactoring really complex and ugly code, I want to be able to see everything that's happening as easily as possible.  So I'd like to do something like

```
// Inclusion of the template library
require_once('lib_template.php');
// Initialization Logic
...lots of ugly non-display code and data-obtaining code here

// Decide what will be able to be output and put it into an array to pass to the template
$template_output_variables = array('name'=>'no name');

// Define the template function here, has html and such in native php here.
$contact_us = function page_contact_us($template_output_variables=null){
// Leave php in the template function.
?>
<body> Hello World
</body>

<?php
}

// call & display the template via delayed execution, display it within a pre-set head and footer.
display_page($template=$contact_us, $template_output_stuff=$template_output_variables, $options=array('title'=>'Contact Us'));
```

### Looking for beneficial techniques for inline "template" sections and clean native php templates

So, I'm wondering what other useful techniques there are out there for making cleaner native-php-template code and I'd also really love to know if someone else out there did a inline-in-file templating system/library/script in php, so I can check it out and use that to inform writing my own.

Here's a github gist of what I have so far:
https://gist.github.com/1201969

Comment: none lol.. maybe just EOF, but not really

Comment: It depends on what your version of "cleaner" is.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: If you want something more like smarty, use smarty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output buffering is a handy tool when lacking a template engine.

```
ob_start(); //start the buffer

echo "some stuff";
include ('sometemplatefile.php');
//etc etc

$body=ob_get_contents(); //get the junk out of the buffer
ob_end_clean(); //clear the buffer

//do search and replace on contents... 
//etc

include ('header.php');
echo $body;
include ('footer.php');
```

Maybe something like heredoc syntax is what you were asking for:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Also, if you have short open tags enabled this can come in handy:

```
Some HTML: 
<?=$data?> 
This is a shortcut for 
<? echo $data;?>
```

I think this may be deprecated in a future version though (I seem to remember reading somewhere)

Comment: Short open tags will be removed some time in the future. However, the "short-open-echo" `<?= ?>` will be part of the language with 5.4

Comment: @KingCrunch Awesome!  Do you know the website you go that info from, because if that's the case, I am going to switch everything to short-open-echo almost immediately.  That will make things so much cleaner.

Comment: Discussion: http://markmail.org/message/6j5iuuleg4oobpic Official RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortags and last but not least the commit: http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=311260 (worth to mention: php5.4 TODO list https://wiki.php.net/todo/php54)

Comment: Ah, although the problem with short tags is apparently that since they're toggleable on and off, if they ever go off, you're spewing your source code out to the world: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/01/12/php-short-open-tag/  Which is compelling.  Thanks for the shorttags info, though, definitely something for me to consider.

Comment: @tchalvak no prob. gonna accept the answer then? heheh

Comment: I don't know, if I get you right (or you me), but at least with 5.4 there is no problem anymore: `<?=` will be always-on.

Comment: Right, which will be cool.  I'm not on 5.4 yet, but that'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but there are so many good tempting engines available I don't see any reason to create your own. There really is very little overhead.

Comment: My problem with existing templating engines right now is: You have to create templates *in a different location*, and switching between two files is something I want to avoid.  I'm refactoring stuff that's horribly intermixed, and I want to be able to create the templates in the same file as the source file, multiple templates, in some cases.

Comment: That's a reasonable excuse :)

Comment: Sorry, this is hard, let me clarify:  I want to be able to create templates without creating files, because they may be very temporary templates used for the purpose of refactoring.   Eventually a whole script may be a template, but to start with, just sections will be, but I'd like to be able to smoothly transition between.  One way that I can conceive of doing that is by creating the templates within the original file, and calling them in that file as well.  Eventually I may be able to move to separate file, but in the early refactoring stages, I may have, say 3 or 4 tiny templates.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems too obscure to me.
What answer you want to get? On what question? I can't get what certain problem you have to solve.

So, I can only comment some of your statements.

> another template engine makes the html/css simpler

It is not true.

> I'd really love to see it if someone else out there did a non-object oriented templating system in php, so I can use that to inform writing my own.

I am such a person.
But, unfortunately, I disagree with this statement:

> having to switch from template to calling script, back and forth, makes it slightly harder to deal with

and I am using separate template for the each page and one main template.
So, only I have to do at the end of script is to assign page template filename and to call main template

```
$page = 'news.tpl.php';
include 'main.tpl.php';
```

and then main template would include $page respectively

Anyway, I see no big problem in your current approach. Just include usual header and footer before and after your "inline" template. that's all

Comment: I'm not being clear, because I find it hard to quantify in my head myself, but:  I'm fine with having seperate templates when I can, when I'm creating the code from scratch, and when using a clean system.  The problem is that refactoring is a totally different beast, and that's what I'm doing now, refactoring ugly procedural code.  Piece by piece.  Parts of a page by parts of a page.  This is why I'm looking for something more basic, more flexible, less dependent on a different file structure, but still seperate-able.  Something that I can have -in- the page while I'm refactoring.

Comment: Tried to clarify some, including that I'm more looking for inline-able templates, I don't really care whether it's OO or not, and part of the difficulty I have with template engines is the added work involved with creating multiple templates (and having them in version control, for example), because in this case I plan to create and destroy the "templates" as necessary to best refactor the code.

Answer (score -1):

'While', 'for', 'foreach', and 'if' all have alternative control structures to make them more template friendly. Really though it's not that hard to close a curly brace with

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Err, right, that's the alternative syntax that I linked to